# Request and compare API Reponses in Oraclize call

Tags: solidity, oracles

I want to send requests to 3 Weather APIs and compare their results like if the rainfall at a specific day were the same London to avoid the single point of failure.

I already learned how I can send multiple requests to APIs. What is the best way to compare their results in Solidity? Is there already a mechanism from oraclize itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing the results of an API call will be the same as comparing any other data in Solidity.

In your example, you are comparing weather, which is likely a `uint256`. You will likely also need the date you are comparing, which would be a timestamp (also a `uint256`). Each of these data sources would need a mapping of timestamp to temperature. The mappings would look as follows:

```
mapping (uint256 => uint256) public sourceOneWeather;
mapping (uint256 => uint256) public sourceTwoWeather;
mapping (uint256 => uint256) public sourceThreeWeather;
```

Comparing them would simply be to put them into a conditional statement and returning the output of whatever comparison you desire.

### Add function example, per comments

An example comparison function would be:

```
function compareResults(uint256 _timestamp) public returns (uint256){
    if (sourceOneWeather[_timestamp] > sourceTwoWeather[_timestamp]):
        if (sourceOneWeather[_timestamp] > sourceThreeWeather[_timestamp]):
            return sourceOneWeather[_timestamp];
        else:
            return sourceThreeWeather[_timestamp];
    else if (sourceTwoWeather[_timestamp] > sourceThreeWeather[_timestamp]):
        return sourceTwoWeather[_timestamp];
    return sourceThreeWeather[_timestamp];
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.

Saving them is no problem. But how i do now, that all 3 Requests gave me an answer so i can call a method to compare the results?

Comment: That simply depends on what you are comparing. You would have to create a function that compares the results, yes. I will add a small example to the code.

Comment: Thanks for the example of code.

But i think you did not understand my question.

As example i want to know, if it really rained in London at the 10th of November 2018. To avoid single point of failure, i want to request at least 3 APIs. 

Requesting these three APIs is no problem. And comparing their results is no problem too. My question is:

How can i know, that all 3 Responses are received so i can compare their results?

Comment: Set an `isReceived` flag after each Oracle call return.

Comment: Ok had that solution in my head. Thought there would be another possiblity. Thank you @shane !